# adb and ifconfig commands not work in intel edison with android things SO

Tags: linux, iot, android-things, intel-edison

I put Android Things SO in my intel Edison with Arduino breakout board.
I run this example [enter link description here](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-simplepio/tree/master/blink)
 and everything worked ok.
But when I try run other code using IO13 I have this issue:

```
 E/HomeActivity: Error on PeripheralIO API
com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: IO13 is already in use But I can not do it.
```

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gPdWq4OH-XOE1kZlpkcUFEY0E/view?usp=sharing)

**I need use adb commands to uninstall packages**

***Can someone help me there?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the release notes:

**Known Issues**

- When multiple activities contain an intent filter for the IOT_LAUNCHER category, the system displays an app chooser that isn't accessible on devices without display support. Android Things only supports a single launcher app, and this behavior will be disabled in a future release.

You have to uninstall the previous app (or close it) because it is holding an open connection to that pin.

You could uninstall that specific app like this:

```
 adb uninstall com.example.androidthings.simplepio
```

Bu you could also use a script to uninstall all other AndroidThings apps (which is handy when you have been playing with a lot of samples).

https://gist.github.com/blundell/7c0c3bb17898b28fe8122b0dc230af50

download and run this script like: `./clear-android-things-apps.sh` and it will uninstall everything

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/issues/509   ?????   I created this issue because upm sensor in intel edison eases and abstracts the programming of i2c drivers in the intel edison

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall `com.example.androidthings.simplepio` package that has been installed from [your example](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-simplepio), execute the following command from your computer (**not** from your device) :

```
adb uninstall com.example.androidthings.simplepio
```